# Why am I not able to extract tweet and user fields using Twitter API v2 and Tweepy in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I know the Twitter API has been changed and a lot of you guys are not using it anymore. Buuuuuut i have kind of a big problem, i started my master thesis in January and i am using the twitter api to extract some tweets. I changed some of my code and i can extract the users and their followers.
I can even extract some tweets but i cant manage to get the extra informations i used to get. So i changed my code to the following:

```
response = client.search_recent_tweets(
        "innovation -is:retweet lang:pl",
        max_results=100,
        tweet_fields=['author_id', 'created_at', 'text', 'source', 'lang', 'geo'],
        user_fields=['name', 'username', 'location', 'verified'],
        expansions=['geo.place_id', 'author_id'],
        place_fields=['country', 'country_code']
    )
```

but when i print my response i dont get the tweet_fields or user_fields displayed. My response looks like this

```
Response(data=[<Tweet id=1661572882110218241 text='Letter W Plane Logo n#Logo #Monogram #Simple #Minimalist #W #Plane #Aviation #Travel #Transportation #Flight #Modern #Creative #Unique #Sleek #Symbolic #Elegant #Artistic #Identity #Typography #Graphic #Corporate #Professional #Distinctive #Innovation'>, <Tweet id=1661439116389613572 text='@EmmanuelMacron  ma swojego @VillaniCedric / matematyk/  a @AndrzejDuda - @AndZyberto ? model?\n strategia global AI #GPAI z  bezzębne  i krajowa z 2018 /choć \'liberalny\' Villani... goal is to build a civil-military complex of innovation/ a "rynki" chwala Tibi Inicjatywe'>, <Tweet id=1661374659244302339 text='News, raczej z tych gorszych.
```

Can someone tell me is it somehow possible with the new api to display those Informations. Im supposed to have the Free Tier, but somehow i can read the data from twitter and not only write 1500 Tweets per month.
In the docs it says i can add the tweet_fields in the Enpoint V2 and display the data, but it doesnt

I tried to add the tweet_fields, user_fields and expected to get the results but i dont. I just keep on getting the tweet_id and the full_text